# Microsoft Access Problem using Combo Box that have the same value to the Bound Column in the dropdown list

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I've been facing trouble with **Combo Box in Microsoft Access Database**. The problem I'm facing is as follows:

Let's say, I've the following question:

**What of the following assistive devices do you use to walk?**

Again let's say, there are several options as a dropdown list for answering the question including their values in braces. I used two columns: **the first column for the text e.g., wheelchair**, and **the second column for the value e.g., (10)**. **I used the value column i.e., the second column as Bound Column.**

➀ Wheelchair (10)

② Walker/Senior Car/Push Cart (8)

③ Double Crutches (8)

④ Two T-shaped Canes (6)

⑤ Single Crutch (4)

⑥ One T-shaped Canes (4)

⑦ Knee Supporter/Brace (2)

Options ② and ③ have the same value that is (8). In this situation, I couldn't be able to place the choice ③. If I choose option ③, it automatically places the option ②. This might be happened due to the same value in options ② and ③. Options ⑤ and ⑥ have the same problem.

In the above circumstances, **keeping the options as it is, could you please give any solution to resolve this problem?**

Thank you very much.

I don't have any idea how to resolve this problem!

Comment: Items should have a unique identifier. You should be saving ID, not text or value. ID should be bound column. What exactly is this 'value' field?

Comment: I think I now know what the value field is indicating. My advice stands.

Answer (score 0):

June is right; you need *three* columns. Thus, if a value list is used, it could be like this (one line of text, no line breaks):

```
1;"Wheelchair";10;
2;"Walker/Senior Car/Push Cart";8;
3;"Double Crutches";8;
4;"Two T-shaped Canes";6;
5;"Single Crutch";4;
6;"One T-shaped Canes";4;
7;"Knee Supporter/Brace";2
```

Bind the combobox to column **1** and set the column width of this to **0** (zero).

If your list separator is comma, replace the semicolons.